# Looking for a breakdown of echo{,} foo

Tags: string, bash, brace-expansion

How does the expression `{,}` work?

I tried searching around SOF as well as on google and even the man pages for bash, yet I haven't been able to come across an explanation for this.

From fiddling around with the expression I've learned that it's some sort of string copying function.

```
echo{,} foo
>> echo echo foo
echo foo{,}
>> foo foo
```

How does this expression work? Is there a name for this? Also, can you provide a practical example for the use of this function?

Comment: It's called "brace expansion". `{,}` uses two empty strings, which is a bit odd in my opinion.

Comment: `mkdir example-{foo,bar,baz}.d` creates `example-foo.d`, `example-bar.d` and `example-baz.d`; `mv foo{,.txt}` renames `foo` to `foo.txt`, whereas `mv foo{.txt,}` does the inverse. The use should be self-evident. That the degenerate case still works... well, why would anyone go out of their way to disallow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" use case for [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is to repeat a string with a substring replaced by each element of a list given in curly braces:

```
$ echo file.{txt,dat,log}
file.txt file.dat file.log
```

Now, if one of the list elements is empty, the string gets printed as is:

```
$ echo file.{txt,dat,}
file.txt file.dat file.
```

A popular use case for this is to rename a file

```
$ mv -v file.txt{,.bak}
'file.txt' -> 'file.txt.bak'
```

This expands to `mv -v file.txt file.txt.bak`, because the first list element is empty.

Now, if *all* elements are empty as in `{,}`, the string just gets printed as many times as there are list elements.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/when-do-you-use-brace-expansion).

Here's a simple explanation.

- `{,}` will repeat left adjacent string exactly 2 times by appending empty strings.
- Similarly `{,,}` will repeat left adjacent string exactly 3 times.
- `var{A,B}` will return `varA` and `varB`

And these examples should clarify more:

```
echo foo{,,}
foo foo foo

echo foo{,1}
foo foo1

echo foo{1,2}
foo1 foo2

echo foo{,,}
foo foo foo

echo foo{1,2,3}
foo1 foo2 foo3
```

[Link to the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)